# Local Notification - Safari on Mac - Working/Not working same time

Tags: javascript, macos, browser, safari, notifications

I am trying [local desktop notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) same code is working for Chrome/Edge/Opera/FF, but in Safari its behaving differently.  Same code is working for one site, but not for other.  In fact two different subdomain behaving differently.

I tried below -

```
Notification.permission // default
Notification.requestPermission(); // get permission
Notification.permission // granted
new Notification('It works!');
```

on two apple's subdomain -

1. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/694834  (**developer** - subdomain) `not working` [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUvIj.png)
2. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251411170    (**discussion** - subdomain) `working` [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PGIA.png)

It works for https://discussions.apple.com, not for https://developer.apple.com.  No error on console, its like Safari just ignored that without any warning/error.

on `Console App` in MAC when I checked I can see -

[image: Msg from Console App]

Comment: In Safari, you can Allow or Deny notifications from specific websites. (Safari, Preferences, Websites, Notifications).  It would be worth double-checking your settings.

Comment: because allowed notification, and if you noticed in attached screenshot it returned granted.  in preference also I have double checked and there also it says allowed for both subdomain developer as well as discussions. all seems good, except not getting notification only.